# Trying to use Pyglet - what does this error mean?

Tags: python, macos, compiler-errors, runtime-error, pyglet

I am running Mac OS X Mountain Lion, with Python 2.7. I did a source install of Pyglet that seemed to go without errors, but any time I try to run a program I get a longish error that I don't understand. It sounds like it has something to do with QuickTime??

Every program I've tried gives the same error. The programs I have tried running are the examples that came in the source, and the example here: http://guzalexander.com/2012/08/17/playing-a-sound-with-python.html

The error I get says:

```
File "examples/media_player.py", line 44, in <module>
from pyglet.gl import *  
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 510, in <module>
    import pyglet.window
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1669, in <module>
    from pyglet.window.carbon import CarbonPlatform, CarbonWindow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/carbon/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    framework='/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 90, in load_library
    return self.load_framework(kwargs['framework'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 226, in load_framework
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(realpath)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: I think that the answer by @user1740200 deserves to be accepted as the solution, because it currently works.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to above, installing my own did the trick best. I adapted the instructions I found on this site: http://twistedpairdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/installing-pyglet-in-mac-os-x/

All I had to do was use pip to install direct from the repository.

> pip install hg+https://pyglet.googlecode.com/hg/

Job Done.

Comment: Worked for me as well. No need to force 32-bit python. Note that cloning the repository might take some time, which appears like `pip` hanging. Alternatively clone with `hg clone` and then `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 2):

I did some more googling, and eventually found a page that addresses this error. Apparently the problem is that Pyglet doesn't like 64-bit architectures. These instructions fixed it for me: [http://roguejs.com/2011-11-22/getting-pyglet-to-work-on-mac-osx-lion/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120320113321/http://roguejs.com/2011-11-22/getting-pyglet-to-work-on-mac-osx-lion/)

> Getting pyglet to work on Mac OSX Lion
>
> November 22, 2011 by roguejs
>
> For those of you who wanted to start doing game development in Python and wanted to use pyglet for it, and you’re using Mac OSX Lion, you’ll most probably come across this error:
>
> OSError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>       /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>   Do not fret – this is merely pyglet 1.1.4 choking on 64-bit architectures (interesting trivia: Pyglet 1.1.4 is currently using the Carbon API, while Pyglet 1.2 is supposed to be ported over to use Cocoa instead).
>
> The easiest way to do this is to force python to go 32bit by typing this in your console:
>
> defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
>   However, just to be safe, I’m going to go through the entire setup steps in case you find any problems with it. Here goes:
>
> Step 1 – install Mercurial in your Mac
>
> Go to Mercurial and download the latest binary for your Mac. Install it, and then open the terminal.
>
> Step 2 – clone the pyglet repository
>
> Create a directory (I did mine in ~/Projects/lib), and clone the pyglet repository into it:
>
> hg clone https://pyglet.googlecode.com/hg/ pyglet
>
> cd pyglet
>
> Step 3 – build it
>
> Now in this step, you can optionally switch to the cocoa-port branch and try it out. Didn’t work for me though.
>
> Optional
>
> hg checkout cocoa-port
>
> Build it
>
> python setup.py install
>
> Step 4 – Force python into 32-bits
>
> Once you’re done, force python into 32 bits with this command:
>
> defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
>   And that’s it! Try building your pyglet app now – they shouldn’t throw the same exception again.

Comment: Forcing python to 32-bits is not needed, see the post below. It might be that the `pyglet` repository included a fix in the meantime for Mac OS X.